# Request to re-open a question

Tags: discussion, status-completed, reopen-closed

A question which I was about to answer was closed as *off-topic because it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem.*: [How do I change the anchor link in JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23547321/html-tree-not-looking-the-way-i-want)

The OP wants to have the link part of the tree node, instead of next to it, and thought he could just put the link inside the node for it to work. And he did put in the question the html code that he tried, as well as an image that explains well the intent I think.

I am not sure why it was closed because according to me the question does have a minimal example of code to reproduce the problem: simply paste the code he provided in one of the node in the jsfiddle that he also provided, and see the result.

Am I the only one who finds the question clear enough to be answered? If not, can the question be re-opened?

Comment: I guess... yes.

Comment: Question askers are expected to put their code into the question, not simply link to a fiddle.   See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149890/prevent-posts-with-links-to-jsfiddle-and-no-code

Comment: Yes George Stocker explained that too, didn't think of it. Thanks.